# Getting ListView Item's Id on Item's BoxView click in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, binding, parameter-passing

I am trying to extract the ListView Item's Id but when I click on the BoxView nothing happens.

This is my XAML(extract from the ListView's ViewCell):

```
<BoxView Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding DetailsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                            </BoxView>
```

And This is my code:

```
DetailsCommand = new Command(ShowDetails);

public async void ShowDetails(object obj)
    {
        var selected = obj as Tasks;
        await _navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(selected.Id));
    }
```

But when I click on the BoxView nothing happens.

Comment: I think your command may be configured wrong. When you use a CommandParameter, I think you have to give the type like `DetailsCommand = new Command<object>(ShowDetails);` Also, make sure that your `ViewCell` isn't capturing the tap and not passing it though to your `BoxView`.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Command` is in the code behind of the **ViewCell**, then you must set the source of your `Command Binding` to the view cell. Example below.

```
<BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding DetailsCommand, Source={x:Reference Cell}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
</BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
```

Then on the ViewCell you need to have the `x:Name` set. This must be set for the **Binding x:Reference** to work.

```
<ViewCell x:Name="Cell">
```

**Edit**

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> ItemsSource { get; set; } = new ...
}
```

**MyObject.cs** -- This is the BindingContext of your `ViewCell`

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public ICommand DetailsCommand { get; }

    // Other properties if needed

    public MyObject(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        DetailsCommand = new Command(ShowDetails);
    }

    private async void ShowDetails()
    {
        var selected = obj as Tasks;
        await _navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(Id));
    }
}
```

In the **MyObject** class, you can pass in an `Id` value when creating your `ItemsSource` and do not need the `CommandParameter` anymore also.

All in all, your `DetailsCommand` needs to be in the **MyObject.cs** class that is being used as an object in your `ItemsSource` and not your ViewModel.

Comment: It is in the ViewModel and ViewModel is set as BindingContext in code behind.

Comment: In that case, the `DetailsCommand` needs to be in the custom object that corresponds to the object in the `ObservableCollection<MyObject>`. The **BindingContext** of the `ViewCell` is the **MyObject** class.

Comment: can you show me some sample please? I cannot seem to work it out

Comment: I edited my answer with a small example of a `ViewModel` and a **MyObject** class that should be the BindingContext of your ViewCell.

Comment: So in xaml I need to do Command="{Binding ItemsSource}" which is the ObservableCollection. right? Or should I leave it bound to the DetailsCommand? I cannot understand why you called observable collection ItemsSource

Comment: Your xaml should stay the same as you had it initially. Post some of your `ViewModel` code where you create your `ItemsSource` for the **ListView**. I can hopefully explain better if I know what your data looks like.

Comment: It all seems to me bit too complicated. I found the solution here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73470/detecting-tap-on-label-inside-viewcell-inside-listview